# Recommended summer schools for this summer [a university student]

Tags: conferences

I am a university student, and I am interested in some pure math areas related to algebra, for example, ring theory like Aliyah & Macdonald (I learned it 60 - 80 percent), algebraic(, or arithmetic) geometry (though I have never learned something like scheme seriously), (algebraic) number theory (I also love other number theories like analytic one), and algebraic topology (I have had a brief lecture on it), although on the other hand I like to cover as many pure math fields, including Lebesgue integral (I finished measure theory), functional analysis, or differential geometry (I have never touched it), as possible. I have finished learning basic topology, real & complex analysis, basic manifolds, linear algebra, groups, basic rings, and Galois theory, and now I am engaged in seminars on Riemann surfaces, and related sheafs.

Now I am searching for a suitable math summer school. I heard from my professor that almost all the math summer schools are for graduat students, or for young scholars, and there are not so many summer schools for university students. That's why I have trouble in searching for nice ones since I can't find anything. Do you have some information about such summer schools?

Comment: ICERM at brown hosts one every summer: https://icerm.brown.edu/summerug/2017/

Comment: @mystupid_acct Thank you very much!

Comment: In the US undergraduates more commonly attend [REUs](https://sites.google.com/site/mathreuprograms/) which are the nearest equivalent to summer schools at that level.

Comment: @NateEldredge I didn't know that. Thank you for the new information! Do you mean this one? https://www.nsf.gov/crssprgm/reu/

Comment: Yes, though not all REU-like programs are funded by NSF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an annual summer school for undergraduates in Lisbon, at the Gulbenkian Foundation. The topic this year is algebraic topology. See https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~ggranja/Talentos/school2017/index.html. The deadline for applying is May 15th (click on the registration link on the left side of the page).

Another international summer school alternates between Lyon and Bremen. See http://math.jacobs-university.de/summerschool/2017/ (don't know why there was no event in 2016), but the deadline for applying this year has already passed.